# Unwanted text in a URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url

I built a web app called [twitterjoindate.com](http://twitterjoindate.com) that allows one to enter a Twitter username and find out when that person joined Twitter.

I noticed that upon entering the URL, the browser shows this URL

[image]

instead of the regular [twitterjoindate.com](http://twitterjoindate.com).

I'm not sure why this is happening- how can it I fix this?

Comment: I think it's a CNAME issue. I think you should be able to disable this behavior...will update if I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-www hostname redirects to the www one.

```
➜  ~  curl -i  twitterjoindate.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 18:57:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Content-Length: 154
Location: http://www.twitterjoindate.com/?from=@

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Check your server configuration and disable any feature to force the www.